# What does an argument with a colon but no default value do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've seen something like this a couple times with ruby/rails code:

```
def self.cool_function(a, b:, c:)
   ...
end
```

But I am having trouble figuring out what it means

Answer (score 6):

It means it's a **required (keyword) argument**.

You can see this by trying to call the method *without* one of those arguments:

```
cool_function(1)
#=> ArgumentError: missing keywords: :b, :c
```

So to correctly call the function, you must include those keywords, e.g.:

```
cool_function(1, b: 2, c: 3)
```

There is lots of documentation and blog posts around this core language feature. For example, you may find [this post](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ruby-2-keyword-arguments) helpful to dig into the topic in much more detail.

Comment: Worth to mention changes coming in Ruby 3.0: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/

Comment: @stolarz ruby 3.0 was released more than a year ago (the changes are upon us) and the syntax provided in this answer is 100% correct for true kwargs.